# java.util.EmptyStackException on JIT/Warmup

Tags: java

I'm using a 3rd party lib in my application that throws a java.util.EmptyStackException

This only happens during the VM JIT/Warmup

- Start application
- Start stress test no rampup.
- java.util.EmptyStackException thrown
- Keep application and redo stress test. No exception thrown
- Shutdown application
- Start application
- Start stress test with rampup. No exception thrown

I could keep reproducing this over and over.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can trace this so I can give more info to the vendor? Or why it could even be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in the vendor lib.  Send them the full stack trace.  Try to write the smallest possible program that can produce this exception in their code and send that to them too.